# Bypassing Trend Micro Officescan Online Website Monitoring

Tags: internet, anti-virus, firewall

I get a free copy of Trend Micro Officescan from my university (the joys of being a computer scientist!), and I have it installed on my computer.

Recently, it has started blocking a website that I go to often, reporting the site as "malicious".

I know the site is not malicious, as I have been using it for some 2 years now. Does anyone know a way to get Trend Micro Officescan to allow me to access this site anyway (despite its own warnings?) short of uninstalling the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run a different version of Trend Micro (wfbsh) at work, but if it is similar to what I see, the clients (users) are managed by a centralized database (server) to manage not just virus dat files, but what content you can and can not access. If you have have the ability to modify the permissions of the client, you should look under a feature called "Website Reputation monitorng" or similar. If you can't modify the client configuration, then absolutely the only way around its settings is to remove it.

On a side note, I have recently started using panda cloud antivirus, I am not associated in any way with them so I'm not providing a link, but I have been using the free client and it is at least as good as any other antivirus software I have come across.